# Codesignal isAdmissibleOverpayment Solution Problem

Tags: python

```
def solution(prices, notes, x):
l=len(prices)
a=0
for y in range(l):
    if('higher' in notes[y]):
        i=notes[y].index('%')
        f=float(notes[y][:i])
        h=prices[y]-((prices[y]*100)/(100+f))
        a-=h
    elif('lower' in notes[y]):
        i=notes[y].index('%')
        f=float(notes[y][:i])
        lo=((prices[y]*100)/(100-f))-prices[y]
        a+=lo
    elif ('Same' in notes[y]):'''don't mind this, this is for my reference to trace the test case for my reference if you want to you can delete this'''
        a+=0

if abs(a)>x:
    return False
elif abs(a)<=x:
    return True
```

I have this problem where all my test cases pass except for the ones below:

```
prices=[40, 40, 40, 40]
notes=["10.0% higher than in-store", 
 "10.0% lower than in-store", 
 "10.0% higher than in-store", 
 "10.0% lower than in-store"]
x=0
prices=[20, 20]
notes=["20.0% higher than in-store", 
 "20.0% lower than in-store"]
x=0
```

The var 'a' in the above code must be zero but has a value when I print it. If more info is needed please refer:https://app.codesignal.com/challenge/pRuhLib5DdetsY4E7

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you are defining "h" as a negative number and "lo" as a positive. You must do it the opposite way ("h" adds to "a" value, "lo" substracts from "a" value) and then remove the abs() function from your last two conditionals (when comparing "a" to "x"):

```
def solution(prices, notes, x):
l=len(prices)
a=0
for y in range(l):
    if('higher' in notes[y]):
        i=notes[y].index('%')
        f=float(notes[y][:i])
        h=prices[y]-((prices[y]*100)/(100+f))
        a+=h
    elif('lower' in notes[y]):
        i=notes[y].index('%')
        f=float(notes[y][:i])
        lo=((prices[y]*100)/(100-f))-prices[y]
        a-=lo
    elif ('Same' in notes[y]):
        a+=0
print('a: ',a)
if a>x:
    return False
elif a<=x:
    return True
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I'll give it a try and see.

Answer (score 0):

So, I tried out this code, and seems like there is an error in the website. The value of a is, in fact `> 0`. Not just in this case, even in the 10th test case. Eg:

```
40 -> 10% higher -> 36.3636
40 -> 10% lower  -> 44.4444
40 -> 10% higher -> 36.3636
40 -> 10% lower  -> 44.4444
# SUM:
160 < 161.616
```

So, the problem is probably bugged. So since `x = 0` Output should be `False` but answer key states True. Please tell me if there is a mistake I made.

Comment: I have no idea, that's my code and I have not been able to fix it for 2 test cases. 'a' should definitely be 0 but it has some values for these two test cases.